# deploying a web service war file to websphere

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, websphere

I am trying to deploy a web service war file to websphere.

I have tested the web service in Eclipse using Tomcat and it worked.  However, once I deploy the war file to Websphere, the service (as outputted in tomcat) does not display.  In deploying to websphere, i checked the DEPLOY WEB SERVICES under the SELECT INSTALLATION OPTIONS.

When I created the war file from Eclipse, I right clicked the application and clicked export file, selected war file and there it went.

Was there something I missed in creating the war file? Or, in the deployment?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late?...See [this case](http://mahichir.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/java-ws-webservices-ibm-websphere-and-eclipse/) for a reasonable explanation.